# Multilingual program with xml

Tags: xml, parsing, multilingual

I want implement multiple languages in my program. I'm using an xml file like this one:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root> 
 <language id="EN">
 <String id="rxtst_found">.rxtst found</String>
 <String id="exe_found">.exe found</String>
 <String id="rxtst_not_found">No .rxtst found</String>
 <String id="exe_not_found">No .exe Found</String>
 </language>
 <language id="DE">
    <String id="exe_found">.exe gefunden</String>
    <String id="rxtst_found">.rxtst gefunden</String>
    <String id="rxtst_not_found">Keine .rxtst gefunden</String>
    <String id="exe_not_found">Keine .exe gefunden</String>
 </language>
     </root>
```

I want to call the language like this:

```
getStringValue(String string_id, language lang) ...
```

Whats the best way to parse the language correctly?
I thought about something like

```
           XmlNodeList xmlNodesByLanguage = xdoc.GetElementsByTagName("language");
...
           String tempLang =  xmlNodesByLanguage.Item(i).Attributes["id"].Value;
```

But I have no clue...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deserialized my xml by using xsd.exe and I read the data by using this code:

```
            //deserializes language xml

            XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(root));
            String asdf = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);

 FileStream fs = new FileStream(asdf + "\\XML\\language.xml", FileMode.Open);

                XmlReader reader = new XmlTextReader(fs);
                //root = head node of the xml file

 root ts = (root)ser.Deserialize(reader);
            fs.Close();
            //sprachennummer nach enum in Siro_Settings
            int languageNr = (int)lang;

            //sucht nach dem passenden Value zu der stringID und gibt ihn zurück
            for (int j = 0; j < ts.Items[languageNr].String.Length; j++)
            {
                if (ts.Items[languageNr].String[j].id.Equals(stringID))
                {
                    return ts.Items[languageNr].String[j].Value;
                }

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use SelectSingleNode method instead and provide a valid XPath for the node that you want to query.

The following sample works well. However its in VB.NET

```
Dim string_id As String = "rxtst_found"
Dim language As String = "DE"

Dim xdoc As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument
xdoc.Load("C:\\sample.xml")

Dim xPath = "root/language[@id='" + language + "']/String[@id='" + string_id + "']"
Dim languageNode = xdoc.SelectSingleNode(xPath)
Dim result = languageNode.InnerText
```